# Mongoose - how to sort by upvote count, if it's a SUM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schemas `User` and `Thread`. They're related through a pivot schema called `Vote`:

```
const VoteSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  thread: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  value: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: value => Promise.resolve(value === 1 || value === -1),
  },
});
```

Needless to say, vote collection will have a reference to a thread, the user who voted, and the vote value which is 1 or -1.

The Thread schema has also a reference to the vote:

```
...
votes: [{
  type: ObjectId,
  ref: 'Vote',
}],
```

So far I've read about `Thread.find().populate('votes')` which will make the votes property contains the documents instead of the ID, but I can't find how to do the SUM operation and order by that value.

How can I sort `Thread.find()` to order based on the `SUM()` of it's 
related `Vote`'s `value` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query in 3.4.

`$lookup` stage is used to pull data from votes collection based on matching votes array followed `$sum` inside `$addFields` to sum the value field inside votes embedded array.

`$sort` stage to sort the input documents based on `value` field descending.

`$project` with exclusion to drop value field from response.

```
Thread.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
    "from":"votes", // name of the collection, not model or schema name
    "localField":"votes",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"votes"
}},
{"$addFields":{"value":{"$sum":"$votes.value"}}},
{"$sort":{"value":-1}},
{"$project":{"value":0}}]).exec(function() {...})
```

Comment: My understanding is that this query will return a plain object, but not a mongoose model object, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. As long as your result contain same fields you can create a model instance from plain object.

Comment: I do intend for the result to contain the same fields as the model. However I'm not sure how to construct those model instances, other than calling `new Thread(result[0]), new Thread(result[1]), etc`. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with mongoose models. May be you can use Array.map to map all the plain objects into new Thread() models at once.